# Fast renormalization of distributions

Tags: distributions, softmax, gradient

Say I have a matrix probs $\in N\times4$ where each row is a categorical distribution.

However I have also a mask $\in N\times4$ that is meant to remove actions that are not available.

What I used to do is to than apply the following:
$$
softmax(probs \cdot mask)
$$
and to do this, I would have in the mask either $1$ or $-\infty$ so that action in the softmax would go to zero, just like what they did in the transformers paper

However, I have a problem with this when a probability in the original distribution is zero, because say I have the following:
$$
probs = [0, .3, .3, .3]\\
mask = [-\infty, 1, 1, 1]\\
softmax(probs\cdot mask) = [0.19803642, 0.26732123, 0.26732123, 0.26732123]
$$
however, in case it's not strictly zero, it works:
$$
probs = [10^{-10}, .3, .3, .3]\\
mask = [-\infty, 1, 1, 1]\\
softmax(probs\cdot mask) = [0.        , 0.33333334, 0.33333334, 0.33333334]
$$

So what I did is stop using softmax and normalizing with the L1 norm... however, now the gradient computation is much slower wrt the softmax, so my question is, is there a way to use the softmax version, without summing an $\epsilon$ to the probabilities at the beginning?

Comment: Define the mask as $0$ in the positions you want to keep and $-\infty$ in the positions in which you want to remove. Would not $softmax(prob + mask)$ solve your problem in any case scenario?

Comment: @LucasPrates thats seems interesting and i think it should work, i’ll test it in the afternoon, in case write and answer and i’ll tell you there